# Pyspark multiple records of same key into single record

Tags: pyspark

I have a data frame as follows -

[Row(account_number=1, address_city='NewYork'), Row(account_number=1, address_address1='hotel road'), Row(account_number=1, address_postal='1345'), Row(account_number=2, address_city='NewJersey'),Row(account_number=2, address_postal='3421')]

I'm trying to transform this into - 
[Row(account_number=1, address_city='NewYork' ,address_address1='hotel road', address_postal='1345'), Row(account_number=2, address_city='NewJersey', address_postal='3421')]

Please suggest the best possible ways to do this.

Comment: Could you provide some exact sample dataframe in the format said if you don;t mind

Comment: Updated in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.pivot`, **`groupBy`** on `id` to get records into single record.

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([("1","address_city","NewYork"),("1","address_address1","hotel road"),("1","address_postal","1345"),("2","address_city","NewJersey"),("2","address_postal","3421")],["id","value","name"])

#+---+----------------+----------+
#| id|           value|      name|
#+---+----------------+----------+
#|  1|    address_city|   NewYork|
#|  1|address_address1|hotel road|
#|  1|  address_postal|      1345|
#|  2|    address_city| NewJersey|
#|  2|  address_postal|      3421|
#+---+----------------+----------+

df.groupBy("id").pivot("value").agg(first("name")).show()
#+---+----------------+------------+--------------+
#| id|address_address1|address_city|address_postal|
#+---+----------------+------------+--------------+
#|  1|      hotel road|     NewYork|          1345|
#|  2|            null|   NewJersey|          3421|
#+---+----------------+------------+--------------+

df.groupBy("id").pivot("value").agg(first("name")).collect()
#[Row(id=u'1', address_address1=u'hotel road', address_city=u'NewYork', address_postal=u'1345'), Row(id=u'2', address_address1=None, address_city=u'NewJersey', address_postal=u'3421')]
```

Comment: Hi Shu.. thanks for the solution but i'm getting this error
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'The pivot column address has more than 10000 distinct values, this could indicate an error. If this was intended, set spark.sql.pivotMaxValues to at least the number of distinct values of the pivot column.;'

Comment: @RAVITEJASATYAVADA, Try to set the value `spark.sql("set spark.sql.pivotMaxValues=1000000").show()` then run the code again!